# Зеркальное отображение элемента

Tags: gwt, javascript, java, css

У меня есть элемент, хотелось бы получить его зеркальное отражение снизу. К примеру, как солнце отражается в воде. Я знаю, для этого, в C# есть специальные классы. Как добиться подобного в CSS+JS и  в CSS+GWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойство в CSS3 `box-reflect`

в WebKit есть `-webkit-box-reflect`

в Мозилла `-moz-box-reflect`

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с JavaScript:

```js
var source = document.querySelector('.elem')
var mirror = source.cloneNode(true)
mirror.classList.add('mirror')
document.body.appendChild(mirror)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.elem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: url('https://vet-omsk.ru/sites/default/files/uzi-cat-1600.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.mirror {
  opacity: 0.3;
  /*transform: rotateX(180deg);*/
  transform: scale(1, -1)
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 60px 0 0 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem"><span>ЗЕРКАЛО</span></div>
```

Comment: должен быть scale по одной оси а не rotate

Comment: по одной оси, scale(-1,1) или scale(1,-1)

Comment: Красиво........

Comment: @Sevastopol' если там был rotatex, значит я ошибся, сбил Вас с толку

Answer (score 1):

Для картинок можно эти библиотеки использовать:

- [Reflection.js](http://cow.neondragon.net/stuff/reflection/)
- [Reflex.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/reflex/)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте поворот объекта через css3 на 180 градусов.

Comment: А Вы когда-нибудь обращали внимание на тот факт, что отражение и поворот на 180 градусов — это разные вещи?))) Не говоря уже о том, что CSS3 это не универсальное (пока ещё) решение, да и качество такого «отражения» будет… ммм… странным.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, сгенерировать тучу div'ов высотой в 1 пиксель и задать им фоновое изображение со сдвигом так, чтобы ряды пикселей шли в обратном порядке. Как это уже сделано [тут](http://studioad.ru/blog/2009-04-11-64).